# Perfectdisk 12.5 and Truecrypt 7.1a with system drive encryption

Tags: truecrypt, disk-encryption

Are these softwares compatible ?
And performance hit level. Does it make my laptop slower I'm using HP pavilion g4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PerfectDisk does not support defragmentation of TruCrypt encrypted drives" from
http://support.raxco.com/KB/a67/how-does-perfectdisk-work-with-whole-drive-encryption.aspx

In truth, as long as you leave around 20%+ free disk space, it is unlikely that you will see any fragmentation issues in general. If you regularly operate below that, then you will see a jump in the amount of fragmentation, especially when working with big files - particularly a problem if the registry has grown big.

In some cases, Windows will actually run FASTER with a fragmented drive due to how information is accessed.

Just be happy with your encrypted drive and don't worry.

Comment: thanks for advice. I may deactivate the Perfectdisk for a while and run a manual defragment if I have to decrypt the drive.